# Definition of isomorphism from Herstein's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition

[image]

The above excerpt is from Herstein's book "Topics in Algebra". It confuses me by two reasons:
Firstly, in the first definition the mapping is *into* but in the second the mapping is *onto*. Why the author uses *into* and *onto*?

Could anyone clarify this distinction in definitions, please?

Comment: What is $\overline{G}$? The image of $\phi$?

Comment: @Rellek, I guess that $\bar{G}$ is group and $\phi$ is the mapping betweeb $G$ and $\bar{G}$

Comment: @Rellek "A mapping $\phi$ from a group $G$ into a group $\bar{G}$ is said to be a
homomorphism if for all $a, b \in G,\ \phi( ab) = \phi(a)\phi (b)$", so according to Herstein it is just another group.

Comment: Perhaps it is simply a typo? Seems unlikely for such a fundamental definition, but maybe Herstein meant to write onto instead of into.

Comment: @Rellek : From a page further back, it's just some codomain group: "Defn.: A mapping $\phi$ from a group $G$ into a group $\bar{G}$ is said to be a *homomorphism* if for all $a,b \in G$, $\phi(ab) = \phi(a)\phi(b).$"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Herstein's terminology (which is rarely used nowadays) an isomorphism is just an injective homomomorphism.

On the other hand, two groups $G$ and $G'$ are said to be isomorphic if there exists a *surjective* (onto) isomorphism $\phi\colon G\to G'$.

Herstein uses the preposition “into” to generically introduce the codomain, so a map $f\colon X\to Y$ is *from $X$ into $Y$*. The preposition “onto” is used when the map is surjective.

The terminology used by Herstein is quite old-fashioned and now it's commonly preferred to say “injective homomorphism” or “monomorphism” instead of “isomorphism”. Note that, in Herstein's terminology, the existence of an isomorphism $\phi\colon G\to G'$ *doesn't* imply that $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic. Only the existence of an “onto isomorphism“ does.

Herstein's book was first published in 1975; at the time terminology was still unsettled, but my algebra teachers always used “isomorphism” for “bijective homomorphism”. It's always best to check the book for definitions and usage and keep a “dictionary” for translations.

Comment: I cannot the understand the meaning of third paragraph of your post. Could you clarify it please?

Comment: @RFZ It's just an explanation of the usage: the symbol $f\colon X\to Y$ is read “$f$ is a map (or homomorphism) of/from $X$ into $Y$” and has no other implications on $f$, unless other conditions are stated. When the words “$f$ is a map of/from $X$ onto $Y$” are used, then it is implied that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: But why Herstein do not add the preposition "onto" when defines the notion of isomorphism? He does it only in the second definition.

Comment: @RFZ Because for Herstein an isomorphism is what is now commonly named “injective homomorphism” or “monomorphism”. Old-fashioned terminology and a confusing one, because the existence of an isomorphism $\phi\colon G\to G'$ *doesn't* imply $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic (in Herstein's terminology, of course).

Comment: Thanks! But how contemporary algebraists define isomorphism?

Comment: @RFZ Nowadays, “isomorphism” commonly means “bijective homomorphism”, but it's always best to check the book for the definition and usage. A book by one of my professors, published in the 60's, still used the old-fashioned terminology. And Herstein's book was first published in 1975.

Comment: I have heard that Herstein's book is good one and I decided to study algebra from that book. And now these definitions confuse me bit

Comment: Still cannot understand. This definition completely confused me. In the first definition $G$ and $\bar{G}$ are groups and he defines isomorphism as homomorphism + injectivity. However, in the second definition he defines the notion of isomorphic group through homomorphism+bijectivity. There is some ambiguity in these definitions.

Comment: @RFZ Yes, it's ambiguous; that's why modern usage is different. Note that the second definition doesn't deal with the term “isomorphism”, but with the *relation* “being isomorphic”.

Comment: What could you suggest me in this situation?

Comment: @RFZ I don't understand. While ambiguous for who's accustomed with modern usage, Herstein's terminology is used consistently across the book.

Comment: P.S. I believe that if in the first definition we replace the word "into" by "onto" then ambiguity will dissappear and things will become clear!

Comment: @RFZ Unfortunately, Herstein uses the word “isomorphism“ in the sense specified in the first definition; if you change it, the book would contain contradictions. It's what it is: when you find “isomorphism” in the book, pretend it's written “monomorphism“.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70732/discussion-between-rfz-and-egreg).

Comment: Herstein was first published sometime before 1975.  It was used in my undergraduate algebra course in 1966 or thereabouts.  Even back then, my teachers said "monomorphism" rather than "isomorphism into".

Comment: @saulspatz I'm talking about the second edition, which probably is what the OP has.